# Laut flüstern bzw. leise rufen

Tags: single-word-request

Manchmal sagt jemand etwas möglichst eindringlich oder laut und gleichzeitig möglichst leise. Wie nennt man das?

*Beispiel:*

> Zwei Soldaten schleichen sich an ein feindliches Lager an. Die Feinde sitzen am Feuer und singen laut. Einer der Soldaten bleibt in einigem Abstand zurück, während sich der andere weiter den Feinden nähert. Da sieht der zurückbleibende Soldat, dass sein Genosse über einen Stapel Glocken zu stolpern droht. Er will ihn warnen, muss also so laut rufen, dass der den Feinden nähere Soldat ihn über deren Singen hört, andererseits darf er nicht zu laut rufen, damit die Feinde ihn nicht hören. Er muss also sowohl laut genug als auch leise genug sein und [flüstert eindringlich]: "Pass auf!"

Die Idee ist, dass die flüsternde Person versucht, ein Geräusch zu übertönen oder eine Distanz zu überwinden ohne von Dritten gehört zu werden. Sie muss also gleichzeitig laut und leise sprechen, was zu einer typischen Intensität des Flüsterns führt. Im Alltag benutzt man diesen Tonfall oft, wenn man jemanden, der Lärm macht (und den Sprechenden nicht hört) zum Leisesein ermahnen möchte, ohne einen schlafenden Dritten zu wecken.

Wenn die 'laut flüsternde' Person wütend ist, kann man *zischen* verwenden: Das DWDS gibt als Bedeutung für *zischen* an: "etw. erbost in eindringlich scharfem, flüsterndem Ton sagen".

Was aber, wenn die Person nicht erbost ist, sondern z.B. ängstlich oder gutgelaunt? Dann passt *zischen* nicht. Was sagt man dann?

Comment: Oxymoron? ;-) ...

Comment: Du hast das sehr gut passende Adverb doch oben mit "eindringlich" schon selbst verwendet? Mir fällt nichts ein, was besser passt.

Comment: Im Kontext des gegebenen Textes finde ich "zischen" gar nicht schlecht. "flüsternd rufen" oder  "rufend flüstern" ist poetisch, aber für Prosa unpassend, scheint mir.

Answer (score 2):

Neben »zischen« gibt es eine mildere Variante, die sich für zornfreie Fälle eignet:

> [zischeln](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zischeln)

Ehefrau zum Liebhaber:

> »Er kommt!«, zischelte sie. »Verschwinde im Schrank!«

Bei Verwendung von »zischeln« wird auch die Assoziation zum feindseligen »[anzischen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anzischen)« vermieden (*jemanden erbost anfahren*).

Comment: Ich würde nicht auf die Idee kommen, dass Menschen zischeln. Für mich zischeln nur Schlangen.

Comment: @Iris: Bist du sicher, dass du _»zischeln«_ meinst und nicht _»züngeln«_?

Comment: Ja, ich bin mir sicher. Züngeln sieht man, zischeln hört man.

Comment: @Iris: Ich wüsste kein Wörterbuch, das _»zischeln«_ mit Schlangen in Verbindung bringt.

Comment: Interessant, ich weiß nicht, woher ich das habe. Vielleicht hatte ja jemand im meinem Umfeld dieses Buch: http://www.verlagruhr.de/wir-zischeln-wie-die-schlange.html

Answer (score 1):

"flüstern" ohne weitere Ergänzung ist in Ordnung. Die Eindringlichkeit wird bereits durch das Ausrufungszeichen ausgedrückt.

> "Pass auf!", flüsterte er.

Mein Vorschlag allerdings wäre: Kein flüstern, zischen, zischeln und erst recht nicht "rufen". Sondern: nichts.

> "Pass auf!"

Ist die Szene ausreichend genau beschrieben, dann ergänzt der Leser für sich das passende *Wie*.

Answer (score -1):

Wie tofro schreibt, hast du bereits eine gute Möglichkeit selbst genannt:

> Er flüstert eindringlich: "Pass auf!"

Von der anderen Seite aus (leise rufen) wäre eine gebräuchliche Variante "unterdrückt rufen":

> Er ruft unterdrückt: "Pass auf!"

Oder du kombinierst es wieder mit dem "flüstern":

> Er ruft flüsternd: "Pass auf!"

Vielleicht erfasst das am ehesten die Bedeutung, die du suchst. Ich weiß allerdings nicht, ob das wirklich so Standardsprache ist. Das Gegenstück "rufend flüstern" würde ich auf jeden Fall nicht verwenden ["rufen" hat eine recht weite Bedeutung - oft "ruft" man nur noch im übertragenen Sinne und ist in der Realität nicht zwangsläufig laut dabei. Zum Beispiel beim altmodischen "Er wird X gerufen" für "Er heißt X". Oder bei Ableitungen wie "ein Gericht/ mit dem Telefon an-rufen". Deshalb kann man das denke ich prinzipiell auch mit "flüsternd" kombinieren. Andersrum ist "flüstern" aber auf jeden Fall leise und "rufend" laut].

An sich sind "laut flüstern" und "leise rufen" aber auch nicht falsch und dürften so verstanden werden, wie du es meinst (auch wenn sich die Paarungen vielleicht etwas widersprüchlich anhören).

Comment: "rufend flüstern" hört sich für mich wirklich schräg und absolut nach Oxymoron an. ("Drinnen saßen stehend Leute...")

Comment: Ich stimme tofro zu. Wie wäre es stattdesssen mit "ruft vorsichtig"?

Comment: @Iris Das wäre dann wieder eine "rufen"-, keine "flüstern"-Variante (dein "stattdessen" passt also nicht ganz - "rufend flüstern" war ja gerade auch die Variante, die ich nicht empfehle). Klingt aber auf jeden Fall passend.